# ElseIf condition doesn't match as expected

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have an HTA that calculates taxes, gross pay and net pay for employees from time in and out entries from text files.

```
' Work time conversion to pay before taxes.
PayPerHour = InputBox("What is " & employee & "'s pay per hour?","Employee Wage")
PayPerMinute = PayPerHour / 60
PayPerSecond = PayPerMinute / 60
PayBeforeTaxes = WorkTime * PayPerSecond

' Calculation of Federal tax up to $600.
WithholdingFederal = InputBox("Number of withholding allowances claimed.")

if WithholdingFederal = 0 then
  if (PayBeforeTaxes < 55) then
    FederalTax = 0
  elseif ((55 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 60)) then
    FederalTax = 1
  elseif ((60 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 70)) then
    FederalTax = 2
  elseif ((70 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 80)) then
    FederalTax = 3
  elseif ((80 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 90)) then
    FederalTax = 4
  elseif ((90 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 100)) then
    FederalTax = 5
  elseif ((100 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 110)) then
    FederalTax = 6
  elseif ((110 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 120)) then
    FederalTax = 7
  elseif ((120 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 130)) then
    FederalTax = 8
  elseif ((130 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 140)) then
    FederalTax = 9
  elseif ((140 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 150)) then
    FederalTax = 10
  elseif ((150 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 160)) then
    FederalTax = 11
  elseif ((160 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 170)) then
    FederalTax = 12
  elseif ((170 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 180)) then
    FederalTax = 13
  elseif ((180 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 190)) then
    FederalTax = 14
  elseif ((190 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 200)) then
    FederalTax = 15
  elseif ((200 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 210)) then
    FederalTax = 16
  elseif ((210 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 220)) then
    FederalTax = 17
  elseif ((220 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 230)) then
    FederalTax = 18
  elseif ((230 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 240)) then
    FederalTax = 20
  elseif ((240 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 250)) then
    FederalTax = 21
  elseif ((250 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 260)) then
    FederalTax = 23
  elseif ((260 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 270)) then
    FederalTax = 24
  elseif ((270 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 280)) then
    FederalTax = 26
  elseif ((280 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 290)) then
    FederalTax = 27
  elseif ((290 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 300)) then
    FederalTax = 29
  elseif ((300 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 310)) then
    FederalTax = 30
  elseif ((310 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 320)) then
    FederalTax = 32
  elseif ((320 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 330)) then
    FederalTax = 33
  elseif ((330 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 340)) then
    FederalTax = 35
  elseif ((340 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 350)) then
    FederalTax = 36
  elseif ((350 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 360)) then
    FederalTax = 38
  elseif ((360 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 370)) then
    FederalTax = 39
  elseif ((370 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 380)) then
    FederalTax = 41
  elseif ((380 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 390)) then
    FederalTax = 42
  elseif ((390 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 400)) then
    FederalTax = 44
  elseif ((400 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 410)) then
    FederalTax = 45
  elseif ((410 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 420)) then
    FederalTax = 47
  elseif ((420 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 430)) then
    FederalTax = 48
  elseif ((430 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 440)) then
    FederalTax = 50
  elseif ((440 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 450)) then
    FederalTax = 51
  elseif ((450 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 460)) then
    FederalTax = 53
  elseif ((460 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 470)) then
    FederalTax = 54
  elseif ((470 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 480)) then
    FederalTax = 56
  elseif ((480 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 490)) then
    FederalTax = 57
  elseif ((490 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 500)) then
    FederalTax = 59
  elseif ((500 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 510)) then
    FederalTax = 60
  elseif ((510 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 520)) then
    FederalTax = 62
  elseif ((520 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 530)) then
    FederalTax = 63
  elseif ((530 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 540)) then
    FederalTax = 65
  elseif ((540 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 550)) then
    FederalTax = 66
  elseif ((550 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 560)) then
    FederalTax = 68
  elseif ((560 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 570)) then
    FederalTax = 69
  elseif ((570 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 580)) then
    FederalTax = 71
  elseif ((580 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 590)) then
    FederalTax = 72
  elseif ((590 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 600)) then
    FederalTax = 74
  end if
end if

' Calculation of taxes and net pay.
MedicareTax = (PayBeforeTaxes / 100) * 1.45
SocialSecurityTax = (PayBeforeTaxes / 100) * 6.20
TaxTotal = StateTax + FederalTax + MedicareTax + SocialSecurityTax
NetPay =  PayBeforeTaxes - TaxTotal
```

All of the `ElseIf` conditions match, except for this:

```
elseif ((80 = PayBeforeTaxes) And (PayBeforeTaxes < 90)) then
  FederalTax = 4
```

It's the only section that doesn't show a value in the input area for Federal Taxes. I can't figure out why. It's just like all the other `elseif`s. Is there another way I can make this work?

Comment: P.S. I'm very new to VBScript.

Comment: Your code is too incomplete. What is the value of `PayBeforeTaxes` and what is `FederalTax`? The code in your question should be a self-contained sample that allows us to reproduce the problem. Also, you do realize that your `ElseIf` conditions check for equality, not if the value is between the 2 margins, don't you?

Comment: Shouldn't all of the `55 = PayBeforeTaxes` be `55 >= PayBeforeTaxes` (from 55-130) ?

Comment: Why would they all be 55 >= PayBeforeTaxes?

Excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't know that, but all except for that one from 80-90 work the way I want them to. Is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: You could simply remove the first clause. Values up to the lower margin are already covered by the previous conditions. Also, please reduce that wall of code. When I said "self-contained" I didn't mean "post your entire code". Sample code should be as small as possible while still demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I'll remember that if I make another post. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I tried it without the first clause, and it works the way I want it to, until it comes to the number 80 (once again)
At 80, it returns the wrong number, even though before 80, and after 80, they return the correct number.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I set `PayBeforeTaxes = 80` the code works as expected. Add an `Else` branch after all the `elseif`s to catch non-matches: `Else : MsgBox PayBeforeTaxes & " (" & TypeName(PayBeforeTaxes) & ")"`. Do you get a message box? If so, what does it say?

Comment: In the full program, when PayBeforeTaxes = 80, it returns 3 for FederalTax. It's supposed to return 4.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Each of your `ElseIf` statements has multiple conditions, but only the first is worth anything because if it's true then the second is necessarily true as well, hence is redundant.

Comment: As I stated, I'm new to VBScript; I've only started learning it a few days ago.

My problem is that even though all of the elseifs work properly, one that is written just like all the others returns a value differently. I've rewritten the elseifs using half as many characters (thanks to Ansgar's comment) but it still behaves differently when PayBeforeTaxes reaches 80.

Comment: Well I tried it myself (by hardcoding PayBeforeTaxes to 80, since you haven't posted the full working code) and it worked fine. So I'd suggest maybe echoing the PayBeforeTaxes value after you calculate it just to ensure that it is in fact 80.

Comment: I did post the full code earlier, but I was told not to do that, sorry. and I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: I decided to continue adding the tax information, and I tested all of the values again. When I tested PayBeforeTaxes at 80 again, FederalTaxes returned 4, like it's supposed to. I don't know what was wrong, but finishing the tax calculation portion seems to have sorted it out. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Every if (a part from first) is:

```
X = PayBeforeTaxes and PayBeforeTaxes < Y
```

This is true only if X=PayBeforeTaxes.
Maybe you mean

```
X >= PayBeforeTaxes and PayBeforeTaxes < Y
```

(first condition redundant but you can leave it if you like).

Since this kind of code is very long, maybe you can consider putting the threashold inside an array

```
eg. upper_bound=[55, 60, 70, ...])
```

declaring another array for the result

```
eg. federalTaxForbound[0, 1, 2, ...]
```

so that in a loop you can find the index of interest.

For example: If PayBeforeTaxes is 68, your index is idx=2 (starting from 0), since upper_bound[idx+1]>PayBeforeTaxes, and your FederalTax is federalTaxForBound[idx]=2.

Just as I would do it :)

Comment: Would doing it that way allow PayBeforeTaxes make FederalTax = a value only if PayBeforeTaxes is at least X, but less than Y?

I started learning VBScript only a few days ago, so sorry for not having a clue, lol.

Comment: Yes. I read your PS only later, so you can follow the if/elseif way: it's a lot easier. :P Just fix the first condition of every ElseIf :)